# Override to use a device's internal microphone only

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, microphone

I need to use the internal iPhone microphone even when a headset with a mic is connected. How do I set it up programmatically?

Comment: can you show your current code?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616536-preferredinput

Comment: @LalKrishna There is no code since I have no idea how to force internal microphone hence I asked the question.

Comment: @OrangeDog I do know how to detect whether headphones are connected.  The subject of the question is different.

Comment: You need to show some effort first before asking a question. See the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Excerpted from **[Apple Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616491-setpreferredinput)**

> Sets the preferred **input port** for audio routing.
>
> ```
> func setPreferredInput(_ inPort: AVAudioSessionPortDescription?) throws
> ```
>
> Setting the preferred input port requests a change to the input audio route. To determine whether the change takes effect, use the
> `currentRoute` property. The value of the inPort parameter must be one of the AVAudioSessionPortDescription objects in the
> *availableInputs* array. If this parameter specifies a port that is not already part of the current audio route and the app’s session controls audio routing, this method initiates a route change to use the preferred port.You must set a preferred input port only after setting the audio session’s category and mode and activating the session.

Answer (score 0):

Used Sivajee Battina's advice to figure things out. This is how I made things work:

```
NSArray *inputs = [audioSession availableInputs];
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *desc in inputs)
{
    NSString *portType = [desc portType];
    if ([portType isEqualToString: AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic])
    {
        [audioSession setPreferredInput: desc error: &error];
        break;
    }
}
```

Still marked his answer as the correct one.